# What would be the most effective way to use Go channels to allow worker threads to communicate with each other?

Tags: go, goroutine

I'm having an issue using channels in such a way for goroutines currently using a resource to signal to other goroutines that the resource is now free. In my assignment, I have to create multiple goroutines to request a process identifier (pid) from a hashmap that maps int64 to bool, with the boolean representing whether or not the pid is in use (true = in use, false = free). So far, this is what I have for my assignment.

```
const MIN_PID int64 = 300
const MAX_PID int64 = 5000
var mu sync.Mutex
var wg sync.WaitGroup

func main() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    pidMap := make(map[int64]bool)
    availableJobs := make(chan int64)

    //First, allocate the pid map, and fill it up with random rumbers.
    allocate_map(pidMap)

    //Afterwards, create the threads to request the pids
    for i := 0; i < 7; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go requestPid(pidMap, i, availableJobs)
    }
    
    wg.Wait()
    close(availableJobs)
}


func requestPid(pidMap map[int64]bool, workerId int, availableJobs chan int64){
    randomSleepTime := rand.Int63n(8) + 1//Between 1 and 8 seconds
    isWaitingForJob := false

    //protect the pid allocation from other threads
    mu.Lock()
    pid := allocate_pid(pidMap)

    //And unlock to ensure multiple threads don't attempt to pull the same pid
    mu.Unlock()

    //Defer the decrement to the waitgroup object until the function returns, accounting for early returns.
    defer wg.Done()
    
    //If there are no jobs to complete, wait for a job to be made available on the channel.
    if pid == -1{
        fmt.Println("worker", workerId, "waiting for a job.")
        isWaitingForJob = true
        pid = <- availableJobs
        fmt.Println("worker", workerId, "received pid", pid)
    }

    fmt.Println("worker", workerId, "is using pid:", pid, "for", time.Second * time.Duration(randomSleepTime))
    time.Sleep(time.Second * time.Duration(randomSleepTime))
    release_pid(pidMap, pid)

    //After this worker is done with the pid, signal that it is available for use.
    if !isWaitingForJob{
        availableJobs <- pid
    }

}

func allocate_map(pidMap map[int64]bool) bool {
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        pidActive := rand.Int63n(2)
        randomPID := rand.Int63n(MAX_PID - MIN_PID) + MIN_PID

        if pidActive == 0{
            pidMap[randomPID] = true
        }else{
            pidMap[randomPID] = false
        }
    }

    return true
}

func allocate_pid(pidMap map[int64]bool) int64 {
    for pid, isActive := range pidMap {
        if !isActive{
            pidMap[pid] = true
            return pid
        }
    }

    return -1
}

func release_pid(pidMap map[int64]bool, pidToRelase int64) {
    pidMap[pidToRelase] = false
}
```

The problem function is `requestPid(map[int64]bool, int, chan int64)`. My goal with this function is to have each goroutine running this function to release the pid they requested, and signal to other threads waiting on in use pids that they are now free to use. In the case that there are more workers than jobs available in the pid map, or when `allocate_pid()` returns -1, I would like for these extra workers to wait until the occupied workers release the pids, so they would be able to use it. I chose to block the goroutine in the if block using a receive command from the `availableJobs` channel, and I am sending an available pid to the `availableJobs` channel when `isWaitingForJob` is `false`.

Unfortunately, I inevitably run into deadlock when there are more jobs than workers due to sending to the channel blocking, as well as when there are more workers than jobs due to receiving from the channel blocking. Is there any feasible way to re-organize this to complete what I sought to do?

I hope I was clear  with my problem.

Comment: Simply using a buffered channel would resolve the deadlock (e.g. `availableJobs := make(chan int64, maxElements)`), but I would rather use a (buffered) channel to enqueue the free pids and also the jobs. Allocating a pid would be simply receiving from the pid channel, and same for the job: sending / receiving on the job channel. This solution naturally solves synchronization and also blocks if no free pid / job. You may also use a non-blocking receive if you do not wish to wait for jobs if none is available.

Comment: Ahh, okay I see. The fix was simpler than I thought. Having a pid channel is an interesting side objective, but I opted to use a buffered channel for `availableJobs` instead, and I also removed the if statement `if !isWaitingForJob`, as it made more sense for all jobs to send to the channel, not just those that received a job first. Thank you!